# Is there a way to connect Xconnect to get all Contacts via sitecore powershell script?

Tags: xconnect, powershell-extensions

Is there a way to connect Xconnect to get all Contacts via sitecore PowerShell script ?

Comment: How would you do this in C#?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/get-contacts.html
This is the one am referring, I'd like to achieve this with in Sitecore PowerShell extensions.